# Is there a way to show/hide divs/form 1 by 1 from db result?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli

I've listed all the questions from my database randomly to a single page and I want to hide every other divs and show them 1 by 1.

I've tried using the LIMIT 1 on my query but the question will be shown repeatedly after processing it.

```
<?php
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_questions ORDER BY RAND();";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$questionCount = 1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$id = $row['id'];
$question = $row['question'];
$choice1 = $row['choice1'];
$choice2 = $row['choice2'];
$choice3 = $row['choice3'];
$choice4 = $row['choice4'];
$answer = $row['answer'];

echo "<div id='d$id'>";
echo "<h4>" . $questionCount++ . ". ". $question . "</h4>";
echo "<input type='radio' id='c1' name='c$id' value='1' checked />" . " 
<label style='font-weight: normal' for='c1'>" . $choice1 . "</label><br/>";
echo "<input type='radio' id='c2' name='c$id' value='2' />" . "<label 
style='font-weight: normal' for='c2'>" . $choice2 . "</label><br/>";
echo "<input type='radio' id='c3' name='c$id' value='3' />" . "<label 
style='font-weight: normal' for='c3'>" . $choice3 . "</label><br/>";
echo "<input type='radio' id='c4' name='c$id' value='4' />" . "<label 
style='font-weight: normal' for='c4'>" . $choice4 . "</label><br/>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit' />";
echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: do you want to execute with jquery/javascript?yes then mention you jquery/javascript code..

Comment: I already tagged javascript/jquery, also tried it but I can't access the id or how to call the loop again without repeating the asked question. Do you have recommendation if I should show everything first or pick randomly from database one at a time? The "admin" can add more questions so it's not fixed.

Comment: If you are working on large data the go with ajax call if not then fetch all data at a time & use hide/show concept.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a new column in the database something column name like 'showhide' and by default put value 'show' and in the Query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_questions WHERE `showhide`='show' LIMIT 1";
```

On clicking submit button UPDATE value in database with value 'hide' so in the next load the submitted row will not come.